# UITableView not displaying data

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am implementing a dynamic table view. This table view controller is pushed in via a button touch on another view controller. But nothing is displayed on the screen even though the log indicates that the cell rows are being set correctly. What could be the reason? I have implemented the number of sections to be 1. Here is the code in the table view controller:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.

NSLog(@"Row count :%d",self.playerNames.count + 1);
return self.playerNames.count + 1;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlayerName";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.row < self.playerNames.count) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.playerNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

NSLog(@"Cell Text :%@",cell.textLabel.text);
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Have you linked the table's datasource and delegate to this controller in interface builder?

Comment: please share the code that adds the tableview to its parent view. If the cells are loading fine then your problem is not in the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

After your tableView is pushed on to the screen, try calling [tableInstanceName reloadData];

Comment: There is only one tableview inside this table view controller.  playerNames array content is initialized in ViewDidLoad:

Comment: Can you please explain why the tableview delegate and datasource need to be set, and where in interface builder? This is a read-only table at this time.

Comment: OK I have set the delegate and datasource for the table view to point back to the table view controller. But it's not even executing the viewdidload any more.

Comment: Also removed the playerNames initialization from viewdidload as I read somewhere that viewdidload is not called. So a method called setplayernames on the table view controller is called in the prepareforsegue. This doesn't work either - why is the table data not being loaded? please help.

Comment: OK figured it out. I had deleted the navigation controller and segues do not work without that. So the net is that it's working after setting the delegate and datasource of the tableview. Thanks!